# What is the meaning of the "?" in this statement in php

Tags: php, class, if-statement, foreach, session-cookies

```
function countproduct(){
        $count = 0;
        $cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart']:array();
        foreach($cart as $row):
            if($row['qty']!=0){
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
        endforeach;

        return $count;
```

i want to know whats the meaning of ? after the isset($_SESSION['cart'])

Comment: Read about short IF syntax

Comment: [Ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

Comment: can i have link

Comment: All it took to find the duplicate was typing “php statement question mark” into Google. Please do some proper research next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ternary operator, these line:

```
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart']:array();
```

Can be transformed to:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
} else {
    $cart = array();
}
```

For more information you can check [php operations documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)